# How can I make my code to generate token and return it to authenticate a user?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, postman

I have the code below for token generation. I follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@siddharthac6/json-web-token-jwt-the-right-way-of-implementing-with-node-js-65b8915d550e). When I use postman to test the code with a registered username and password, it returned the `JsonWebTokenError: jwt malform`. On close review, I discovered that the error comes from `jwt.verify` section.

1. What do I need to adjust so that the token can be generated?
2. How can I configure it so that when a users makers a log in request, say he's passing his username and password, along with email and password, the client must pass a client identity ( [payload + clientID] ), for the server to know for whom the token is to be signed.
3. Is there any special value I need to pass in `Postman Header` to test the working of the token system?

**CODE EDITED**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const fs = require('fs');

// PRIVATE and PUBLIC key
const publicKey = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/public.key', 'utf8');
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/private.key', 'utf8');

// Returns secret only known to server at runtime
exports.getSecret = () => {
  const secret = require('../config/secret.json').secret;
  return secret;
};

// Returns token
exports.getToken = (payload, signOptions) => {
  if (!signOptions) {
    signOptions = {
      issuer:  "Myself",
      expiresIn:  "30d", 
      algorithm:  "RS256"
    }    
  };
   const token = jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, options);
  return (token);
};

// Returns result of token validation
exports.validateToken = (token, verifyOptions) => {

  if (!verifyOptions) {
    verifyOptions = {
      issuer:  "Myself",
      expiresIn:  "30d", 
      algorithm:  "RS256"
    }    
  };
  try {
    return jwt.verify(token, publicKey, verifyOptions);
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
};

// Returns validation result of token
exports.token_post = (req, res) => {
  res.send(this.validateToken(req.header.Authorization, this.getSecret()));
};

exports.hasPermission = (token, resource) => {
  const result = this.validateToken(token, this.getSecret());
  console.log(result);
  if (result.name === 'JsonWebTokenError') {
    return false;
  } else if (result.permissions) {
    let permissionSet = new Set(result.permissions);
    console.log('permissions in token', JSON.stringify(permissionSet));
    return permissionSet.has(resource);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not feeding the good arguments to `this.validateToken`.

You should give it the `verifyOptions` instead of `this.getSecret()`.

By the way, this is not a secret but a public key so I don't recommend using this name. And you are reading the public key twice.

Your `hasPermission` function should look like that:

```
exports.hasPermission = (token, resource, $Options) => {
    const result = this.validateToken(token, $Options);
    console.log(result);
    if (result.name === 'JsonWebTokenError') {
        return false;
    } else if (result.permissions) {
        let permissionSet = new Set(result.permissions);
        console.log('permissions in token', JSON.stringify(permissionSet));
        return permissionSet.has(resource);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Don't forget to change the code that call that function. `$Options` is the one you use to sign your token, the `signOptions` in the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks @Waelmio. Let me try and adjust my code. By the way, where would you suggest I use the public key?

Comment: I tested it and it works for me. I will post the code by editing my answer.

Comment: I see you changed your code but what is the return value of `getSecret` here ? If it's not the `signOptions` it still won't work. You have to give these options to verify the token.

Comment: @JetroOlowole And what do you mean by 'Where would you suggest I use the public key ?' ?

Comment: Thanks Waelmio. Seeing this late. Let me try this solution first.